# Plotting a line between certain points in a function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to draw the response of an envelop detector, to do that I need to draw lines that connects between specific points such as the points of

```
(x=0,(1.5+0.8*cos(x*2*180/pi))*cos(x*20*180/pi)) and (x=1.9*pi,(1.5+0.8*cos(1.9*pi*2*180/pi))*cos(1.9*pi*20*180/pi))
```

How can modify the line     `\addplot[domain=0:2*pi,lava,samples=500] {(1.5+0.8*cos(x*2*180/pi))*cos(x*20*180/pi)};` to do that

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
      hide axis,
      x=1cm,y=1cm,
      /tikz/line cap=rect, /tikz/line join=round
    ]
\addplot[domain=0:2*pi,black,samples=250,dashed] {0.8*cos(x*2*180/pi)+1.5};
\addplot[domain=0:2*pi,black,samples=250,dashed] {-(0.8*cos(x*2*180/pi)+1.5)};
\addplot[domain=0:2*pi,lava,samples=500] {(1.5+0.8*cos(x*2*180/pi))*cos(x*20*180/pi)};
\end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: While not a big deal in this case, it's always nice if you make complete examples, and test them before posting :) Here, `lava` is not a colour that's defined by default, so anyone trying your code has to realize that and then change the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a list of x-values to evaluate a function with the `samples at` key, e.g.

```
\addplot[domain=0:2*pi,blue,samples at={0,5.969}] {(1.5+0.8*cos(x*2*180/pi))*cos(x*20*180/pi)};
```

It seems like those values aren't evaluated as math expressions though, as using `1.9*pi` in the coordinate list didn't work. Hence 5.969 instead.